# How to ensure the traffic between vm and host doesn't mix in Windows?

Tags: virtualization, isolation

I'm looking forward to using a volatile VM. And according to this source :

> By default, network address translation (NAT) is configured by the virtualization software such that the guest OS shares an IP address with the host. Effectively, this means the two share an internet connection and packets could be intercepted, in both directions on both machines.

But what about using bridged adapter ? It has it own local IP so it talks directly to router I thought ?

Can someone more knowledgeable explain why this is not the case, if a external WiFi adapter is the only true solution, and regarding this topic how other options like " Internal Network " and " Host-Only network " apply.

I'm talking about VirtualBox or similar under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a bridged configuration then NAT will not occur. The guest system will request and configure its own IP address from the adjacent segment. If you have the guest configured in a shared configuration then an IP addressed will be assigned by your virtualization software and NAT will be used to communicate with the adjacent network segment.